# $limit get ignored after $unwind with mongo aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure in my mongo documents:

```
{
   "_id":"EAovkxq63eXshdEb5",
   "gender":"man",
   "firstName":"Test",
   "lastName":"Test",
   "otherFirstName":"",
   ...
   "cooperatives":[
      {
         "cooperativeId":"xaPFLy2XbJFsDA2st",
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

I try to only get cooperator with cooperatives.cooperativeId with a certain value and I also try to filter out the sub array cooperatives to keep only one. Finaly, I need pagination to only keep a certain amount of data back to the front end :

```
cooperators.aggregate(
   { $match: query },
   { $sort: {'displayName':1} },
   { $unwind: '$cooperatives' },
   { $match: { 'cooperatives.cooperativeId': 'myid'} },
   { $skip: 10 },
   { $limit: 50 }
);
```

The result returns all the document matching my criteria but $skip and $limit are completely ignored.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The `aggregate` method expects the pipeline in an array, not separate parameters. Can you try that?

Comment: Right... Sometimes it's quite difficult to see something like this ! Thanks :-)